# Non-type templates for logic splitting

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have the following situation and I don't know if my approach is right. I am working on a project that has the following structure:

```
class Filesystem {
public:
      Filesystem(Profile* profile);
      OpenFile(const std::string& file,OpenFileCallback);
      ReadFile(int file_handle,Buffer* buffer,ulong offset,ulong length);
protected:
    DiskRouter* disk_router_;
...
}

// --- implementation ---
Filesystem::Filesystem(Profile* profile) 
    :disk_router_(Disk_Router::Get(profile)){
}
```

This class uses an Operation abstraction to run OpenFile operations, ReadFile operations and so on. The operations are sent to a router that is responsible with the type of file system in question.

```
class Operation {
public:
    Operation(Disk_Router* router) {
    }
}
```

I want to use a non-type parameter that chooses the destination router and a destination Policy to choose between the routers. Basically the code is reusable and I don't want to change a good implementation and if something ever changes to be available for all logic.
Something like:

```
template <int DESTINATION>
class Filesystem{
 ...
protected:
  Destination_Policy<DESTINATION>::DestinationType router_type;
}
// ----- implementation
template <int DESTINATION>
Filesystem<DESTINATION>::Filesystem(Profile* profile)
      :disk_router_(Destination_Policy<DESTINATION>::Get(profile)) {
}
```

The Operation will become:

```
template <class Destination>
class Operation{..}
```

What I am trying to achieve:

- I don't need to describe a general interface for the routers. They can    vary independely
- I can specialize certain methods if needed based on the non-type

Is this logic correct?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind, but since your question only shows a small part of your code, only you can judge if they apply:

The first thing is that `int` does not have any real meaning. I'd assume that the number of possible values and their meaning should be limited to a specific set, hence using an `enum` (or even better a `enum class` if C++11 is available) seems more appropriate. You can still specialize as with the `int`, just your code will become more readable and less error-prone.

But the second thing and IMHO the real question is, why do you need the non-type parameter at all? It looks like you can simply pass the policy type directly:

```
template <typename DestinationPolicy>
class Filesystem{
 ...
protected:
  typename DestinationPolicy::DestinationType disk_router_;
}
// ----- implementation
template <typename DestinationPolicy>
Filesystem<DestinationPolicy>::Filesystem(Profile* profile)
      :disk_router_(DestinationPolicy::Get(profile)) {
}
```

etc.

If most of your policies end up looking almost the same, create a base class for them and only overwrite what is needed for the real policies. It will also make you more flexible compared to an `enum`-based solution as you can add any number of policies later on and give each policy a descriptive name.

Comment: Yes, I am using an enum, but directly using the destination policy makes more sense. I am still analyzing if an adapter for the DiskRouter that abides an interface doesn't apply. But it means more code change and several interface restrictions with which I am not comfortable.